# No output from xpath using nokogiri

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/"))  

puts page.xpath(".//*[@id='offset']/span[1]").text
```

this should output the gmt time but it outputs nothing, what could be the reason?

Comment: That page does not contain any element with id="offset".

Comment: In fact, it does. http://i.imgur.com/zMSBj.jpg wtf happens there?!

Comment: Oh, it's in an `iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you want to find is hidden in an `iframe`. The URL you want to open is `http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time/scripts/clock-8/runner.php?tz=gmt`. You could get it from `src` attribute of the `iframe` element on the original page.